# While replacing the element getting IllegalArgumentException in Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to replace the td which is having colspan attribute, getting the attr value I will replace the td's accordingly.

Here is my code

```
public static String getParsedHtml(String html)throws Exception{
        try {
            if(html!=null && !html.trim().isEmpty()){
                Document htmlDoc=Jsoup.parse(html);
                if(htmlDoc!=null){
                    System.out.println(" >>>>> " +htmlDoc );
                    Elements colspanElms=htmlDoc.select("td[colspan]");
                    if(colspanElms!=null && colspanElms.size() > 0){
                        for(int col=0;col<colspanElms.size();col++){
                            Element colspanElmt=colspanElms.get(col);
                            String tdValue=colspanElmt.text();
                            int colspanValue=Integer.parseInt(colspanElmt.attr("colspan"));
                            for(int tdGen=0;tdGen<colspanValue;tdGen++){
                                String template="<td>"+tdValue+"</td>";
                                Element replaceElm = Jsoup.parse(template, "", Parser.xmlParser());
                                colspanElmt.replaceWith(replaceElm);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("colspanElms is null or empty"+colspanElms);
                    }
                }
                html=htmlDoc.html();
            }else{
                System.out.println("html is null or empty");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return html;
    }
```

I checked by debugging, At the second time of looping in

```
for(int tdGen=0;tdGen<colspanValue;tdGen++){
    String template="<td>"+tdValue+"</td>";
    Element replaceElm = Jsoup.parse(template, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    colspanElmt.replaceWith(replaceElm);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<td class="td_0_1" colspan="3">Seguros de Personas</td>
```

I am having TD as above with colspan value, I need to replace that TD with the number of colspan value. For Example from the above I need to replace TD by 3 TD's

I am getting **IllegalArgumentException: Object is null** , But the object has value.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your HTML.

Comment: Will update with the HTML now: 2 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a compiler here to test, but are you sure the loop is doing what you want? Because you replace `colspanElmt` inside the loop, but it is set only once outside the loop! So The loop will continuously replace the same element.

That brings me to the guess, that the `Element replaceElm` is not really correctly build and is actually `null`. You can check with a debugger or println. This fits your finding, because first time in the loop you replace `colspanElmt` with `null`, which works, but second time you try to call `replaceWith` on null, which gives you an Exception

Comment: At the first the element is replaced, the very next time exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, as I explained. I think you are replacing the the same element several times, which makes not much sense. I think you need to replace the colspan element and then add the missing number of td elements as siblings to the first replaced element (add, not replace)

Comment: I have updated the question, The td which I need to replace with appropriate to colspan value. Please check

Comment: I have no time now, sorry. But look into this: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my self..

Here is my Code

```
public static String getParsedHtml(String html)throws Exception{
        try {
            if(html!=null && !html.trim().isEmpty()){
                Element htmlDoc=Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
                if(htmlDoc!=null){
                    Elements tdElements=htmlDoc.select("tr > td[colspan]");
                    if(tdElements!=null && tdElements.size() > 0){
                        int tdSize=tdElements.size();
                        String tdTemp="";
                        String temp="";
                        for(int td=0;td<tdSize;td++){
                            Element colSpanElement=tdElements.get(td);
                            temp=colSpanElement.toString();
                            String attrValue=colSpanElement.attr("colspan");
                            if(attrValue!=null && !attrValue.trim().isEmpty()){
                                int iColSpanVal=Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
                                for(int col=0;col<iColSpanVal;col++){
                                    Element newTd=tdElements.get(td).clone();
                                    newTd.removeAttr("colspan");
                                    tdTemp=tdTemp+" "+newTd.toString();
                                }
                                System.out.println("tdTemp: " + tdTemp);
                            }
                            if(!temp.trim().isEmpty() && !tdTemp.trim().isEmpty()){
                                System.out.println("temp: " + temp);
                                System.out.println("tdTemp: " + tdTemp);
                                html=html.replace(temp, tdTemp);
                                temp="";
                                tdTemp="";
                            }
                        }//End of Td loop
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("tdElements is null or empty : "+tdElements);
                    }

                }else{
                    System.out.println("htmlDoc is null "+htmlDoc);
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("html is null or empty " + html);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        System.out.println("html:: " + html);
        return html;
    }
```

Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: I am glad you figured it out!

Comment: Yup, just used a String function :)